# Android Gradle unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, ssl, gradle, keystore

I have problem with gradle download dependencies from **jcenter**.

I work in coprorative network and connect to internet via proxy.

I maked all necessary settings in gradle.properties for proxy:

```
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout=360000
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout=360000
systemProp.http.proxyHost=10.8.54.68
systemProp.http.proxyPort=9090
systemProp.http.proxyUser=HCB\\SAxakalov
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=****
systemProp.https.proxyHost=10.8.54.68
systemProp.https.proxyPort=9090
systemProp.https.proxyUser=HCB\\SAxakalov
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=****
```

Also add necessary server's certificates in:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

Also add necessary server's certificates in Android Studio settings:

```
Settings->Tools->Server Certificates
```

Android Studio version is 3.2.1

Top-level build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
    google()
    maven { url 'http://central.maven.org/maven2' }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release'}
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.github.JakeWharton:sdk-manager-plugin:1d29782dd6ffa18880c8cbada748fb3dea45e7be'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

I also had problem with other resources like:

> http://central.maven.org
>
> https://jitpack.io
>
> https://maven.fabric.io
>
> .......................

But after adding certificates into cacerts for this resources problem disapear.

Ofcourse, I added server's certificate from https://jcenter.bintray.com. 
But I don't understand why some dependencies didn't download, but some dependencies downloaded from this resouces, and android studio show error **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**.

For example this dependencies cannot download:

> Metadata of https://jcenter.bintray.com/quoin/quoin/0.1.2/quoin-0.1.2-sources.jar

And for this reason I opened this link from browser and can't find this jar file, but android studio search it and show error **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**.

I re-installed Android Studio, also reboot OS. It doesn't help.

Screen:
[image]